# after a click-event: how do i add somehting to a URL via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, iframe

i wanted to find a simple method to get a custom preview-image to my videos within my blog by hiding them and make them visible right after click on the preview-image. the user Dominic Green helped me to get it nearly started.

the problem is: the video already starts to play (even if it is hidden) in autoplay-mode right after the pageload (you can hear the sound in the background) but i want to have the autoplay to start right after click on the preview-image...

in this example i already added "autoplay=1" manually but i want to add this line via javascript to the video-URL right after the click!

here's the example how i did it so far (click on the flower-images will make the video visible): http://brayaz.de/test/example.html

i'm absolutely not into javascript so any help would be great!
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the source of the iframe to include the autoplay :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".video").hide();
    $(".loader").on('click', function(){
        $(this).hide();
        elm = $(this).siblings(".video")
        elm.show();
        var iframe = elm.find('iframe');
        iframe.prop('src', iframe.prop('src')+'&autoplay=1');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q9mUJ/)

Answer (score 1):

### HTML Code

```
<param name="myvideo" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/v_MVwUqrwDc?rel=0">
```

### JQuery

```
$('param[name="myvideo"]').val(function(i, oldVal) {
    return oldVal + (oldVal.indexOf('?') ? '&autoplay=1' : '?autoplay=1');
});
```